# How can i get ISP from maxmind GeoIPISP.dat using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, maxmind

I want to get ISP from GeoIPISP.dat file using vb.net windows application.

Answer (score 0):

They do not have any vb.net documentation listed on their site. They do however have C# examples.

Try referencing their documentation here: 
http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-dotnet/

You could also use http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert pieces over to VB.net as needed.

Comment: That API only works with the GeoIP2 databases, including GeoIP2 ISP. To use a legacy database like `GeoIPISP.dat`, you would need to use [the legacy API](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-csharp2). That said, I would recommend using the GeoIP2 ISP database with the GeoIP2 API if you can.